# What is the meaning of => operator in a Rake task?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am trying to understand an existing Ruby code. Below is a code snippet:

```
 file File.join("ext", "abc") => ["ext/pqr"] do
      puts "In"
      #some more content
 end
```

I understand from the documentation that File.join will generate the path "ext/abc". But what does the "=>" operator here do ? When is the body of the "do" executed?

Comment: @Sinstein It looks like a Hash. But it is a Rake task dependency syntax.. Not the one you marked as a _dup_.

Comment: The OP read [this section](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/doc/rake/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-File+Tasks)

Comment: @ArupRakshit "rake task dependency syntax" is also a hash.

Comment: @MarekLipka Yes. But the dup question no way explaining everything.. Which questions are answered from these - (a) But what does the "=>" operator here do ? (b) When is the body of the "do" executed?

Comment: @MarekLipka Maybe the dup talks about the same operator/operation but it does not really about rake task dependencies. Someone else having a similar question won't find the answers in the original question

Comment: The correct statement is

    file File.join("ext", "abc") #=> ["ext/pqr"] 
     do
          puts "In"
          #some more content
     end

It is a comment displaying the file path created.

Comment: @Sinstein you may be right, but if so, the question needs modification, 'cause the title is misleading. Could you do it?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask two questions, not ask two questions within a single question. Note, however, that both of your questions have already been asked and answered here on StackOverflow: the `=>` is not an operator, it's part of Ruby's `Hash` literal syntax, and the `do`/`end` is part of Ruby's block literal syntax; both `Hash`es and blocks have been extensively covered on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `=>` is used to define a key/value item in an [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) in Ruby.

```
2.1.5 :002 > hash = { :foo => 1 }
 => {:foo=>1}
```

In your particular case, the result of `File.join("ext", "abc")` (which is a `String` representing a path on the file system) becomes the key of a Hash item where the value is an array.

```
file "ext/abc" => ["ext/pqr"] do
  puts "In"
  #some more content
end
```

`file` in `rake` is used to define a [file task](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/doc/rake/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-File+Tasks). The array in the Hash represents the array of file dependencies.

In other words, you are telling `rake` to perform something in order to create the file `File.join("ext", "abc")`, but before executing the task (represented by the Ruby code within the `do/end` block it must execute all the tasks matching the files defined in the array, as long as they don't exist yet.

You can find more about the File tasks in the [official Rake documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/doc/rake/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-File+Tasks).